# Run jQuery Web App on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, web-application

I built a web app powered by jQuery and Basic Primitives APIs. The app reads a CSV file and then displays several charts based on this information. I want to know if it is possible to upload it to SharePoint so users can access it and run it from there.

Comment: Are these API client side or server side?

Comment: These files will reside on the SharePoint server, and will run in the client browser once the application is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

All css and js files can be placed in Site Assets document library.
You can create pages and using SharePoint designer you can reference the CSS and JS files and also add HTML code into the page.

If you are looking for deployable solution, then you should create a Visual Studio solution. Choose SharePoint project template and place files in proper order.

If your application uses server side code (3rd party libraries) then you need to install those as a pre-requisite.